# Use a for loop to create a set of turtles from a list in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, turtle-graphics

I'm attempting to create a list of turtles in Python. I can achieve this manually by the following:

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()

one = turtle.Turtle()
two = turtle.Turtle()
```

I'm hoping to iterate through a list of turtle names using the following for loop, but the syntax is throwing me:

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()

for turtleName in ["one","two"]:
    turtleName = turtle.Turtle()

one.left(60)
one.forward(160)

NameError: name 'one' is not defined
```

Comment: don't do this. use a `dict`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
for turtleName in ["one","two"]:
    turtleName = turtle.Turtle()
```

You're creating a variable inside this loop and for each value inside your list, it's getting its value.

For an example, in the first iteration, the value inside turtleName will be 'one' and in the second iteration it will be 'two'.

When you do

```
turtleName = turtle.Turtle()
```

You are overwriting the value that turtleName was given by the loop.

What you want is to create variables dynamically, which I don't know if it's possible, but you can use dict to do something close to what you want, for an example, you can try

```
names = ['one', 'two']
turtle_dict = dict()

for name in names:
   turtle_dict[name] = turtle.Turtle()
```

So when you want to call the turtle by its name, you can do

```
turtle_dict['one'].left(60)
```

or

```
turtle_dict['two'].left(60)
```

For more information about how dict work, you can check in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

I hope this helps :)

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do at

```
for turtleName in ["one","two"]:
    turtleName = turtle.Turtle()
```

is assigning the variable turtleName the value "one".
Like what  juanpa.arrivillaga said, use a dictionary.

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
dict = {}
for turtleName in ["one","two"]:
    dict[turtleName] = turtle.Turtle()

dict["one"].left(60)
dict["two"].forward(160)
```